# XML Schema - cannot find the declaration of element

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, xml-validation, xml-error

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rootItem xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="schema.xsd">
    <product category="software" type="individual" currentlyOffered="Y">
        <tid>725</tid>
        <tname>MS Office</tname>
        <reviewDate>2017-12-05</reviewDate>
        <note staffID="ee21kfj">Need to specify Windows version</note>
        <note staffID="ef23mls">Is there a price update?</note>
    </product>
    <product category="hardware" type="individual" currentlyOffered="TBC">
        <tid>511</tid>
        <tname>Mouse</tname>
        <reviewDate>2016-09-26</reviewDate>
        <note staffID="fh26eij">Need to ensure ... minors</note>
        <note staffID="mm25por">Need to check ... this</note>
    </product>
</rootItem>
```

XML Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <!-- definition of simple elements -->
    <xs:element name="tid" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
    <xs:element name="tname" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="reviewDate" type="xs:date"/>
    <xs:element name="note" type="xs:string"/>

    <!-- definition of attributes -->
    <xs:attribute name="category" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="currentlyOffered" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="staffID">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <!-- Some Rules -->
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>

    <!-- definition of complex elements -->
    <xs:element name="product">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <!-- Some Rules -->
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="rootItem">
        <xs:complexType>
            <!-- Some Rules -->
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

And the response I get is:

```
"Cannot find the declaration of element 'rootItem'.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it the XML file or the XSD that you seek to change to get validation to succeed?

Comment: The XSD as I'm 99% sure it's a complete balls-up by me.

Answer (score 1):

your xml instance uses the default namespace `xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"` which is not defined in your schema. I don't know which part of your data is changeable, but you either have to remove the namespace in the XML or add it as `<xs:element name="rootItem" xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com">` in your schema.

(Have a look at the comment of Michael Kay where the right action to correct the schema file is mentioned)

Comment: The diagnosis is correct but the solution is wrong. If you want the schema to be applicable to namespace `http://www.w3schools.com`, you need to put this in the targetNamespace attribute of the xs:schema element.

Answer (score 0):

Add target namespace to schema:

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```